# Is $C^\infty([0,T]\times \Gamma) \subset C^\infty([0,T];H^1(\Gamma))$? If so, is it dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Gamma$ be a $(n-1)$-dimensional compact hypersurface (with whatever smoothness is required). Is it true that
$$C^\infty([0,T]\times \Gamma) \subset C^\infty([0,T];H^1(\Gamma))$$
holds? I'm not sure that it is since if $\varphi \in C^\infty([0,T]\times \Gamma)$ and $t_n \to t$ we would need for example $$\int_{\Gamma}|\varphi(t_n)-\varphi(t)|^2 \to 0$$
and I don't see that this holds. But the domain is compact and we do have uniform convergence...

Is the inclusion dense if it is an inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true and it is dense.

If $f\in C^\infty([0,T]\times \Gamma)$ then $\partial^n_t u$ clearly is $C^\infty$ is $t$ and belongs to $H^1(\Gamma)$, for all $t\in[0,T]$, as it is sufficiently smooth with respect to the variables which paprametrize $\Gamma$.

Also, as $\Gamma$ is compact and smooth, $H^1(\Gamma)$ is the completion $C^\infty(\Gamma)$.